# Error while trying to login with react native google sign-in

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm using [React-native-google-sigin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin) package. I have followed the instructions and registered the app in Firebase.io, created SHA256 key using keytools and added to the firebase and enabled the google login.
Added **google-services.json** to **android/app** directory.

Everytime i try to login, it is throwing this error, please help:

```
Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred
at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:146)
at NativeModules.js:95
at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:397)
at MessageQueue.js:127
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
at debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Answer (score 3):

Steps to fix:

1. Go to console.developer.google.com
2. Select the project.
3. Go to Credentials.
4. Switch to O Auth Consent screen.
5. Change the app name and fill email id (optional)
6. Save at the bottom

Try logging in now and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same error it took a whole day for me to solve it. It was because of the SHA -1 certificate problem. i gave the value from different keystore in the firebase ,hence google-services.json had some wrong client id which was making the request fail so i did the following steps.
1)deleted the SHA-1 key from firebase
2) generated the key  (referring to this article ->[ https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth ]) 
3)placed the key in the fire base and generated new google -services.json file

always use :-  `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore`
commond **dont even change the path**(in windows) 
**default password:-android**

Answer (score 0):

On Your Emulator or device, Click on 3 dots on the right side and click `Google Play` and Update the Version.

Open `Google Playstore` On your device and search for `Google Play Services`, Update it.
Run Your App now.

Answer (score 0):

The SHA-1 key in the firebase console must be incorrect or not present.

1. To add this key navigate to android folder using following command

`cd android`

2. Run the 2 following command and copy the 2 SHA-1 keys.

`keytool -list -v -keystore .\app\debug.keystore` 
  add your .keystore file path insted of `.\app\debug.keystore` and copy generated SHA-1 key and paste it as per step 3

and

`./gradlew signingReport` again copy generated SHA-1 key and paste it as per step 3.

3. Paste these SHA-1 keys on **Firebase Console->Project Setting->your Apps->add fingureprint** and paste the SHA-1 keys here